# Class 'SoapClient' not found in.. wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /hoe/roits/wp.com/wp-content/plugins/Aggmges/classitle.php on line 51
```

Worpress doesnt seem to have the latest php installed as I understand. What can I do to install the newest php or make it so that the SoapClient will work in worpress?

Comment: why to close?...........

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php

Install the php soap module if you don't have it, and make sure enabled in php.ini

Comment: so i need to check the host , if he can install it? I dont have access to the files..anyway.. right?

Comment: yes it should be a simple job for your host, try create a new page containing <?php phpinfo(); ?> and browse to it. Should show if it is installed etc.